# Navigating USSD menu in the dial string

Tags: ussd, telecommunication

I'm looking for a way to interact with USSD menus through the dial string itself.

e.g. the dial string activates the USSD menu from the carrier and automatically enters in the menu option and submits it to the USSD application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late but I have just signed up to answer your question. So, our operator has ussd menu that opens up when you dial *100#, and then you have options for checking your account amount, pay parking, send money to prepaid number, etc. which are organised like

1. Check account
2. Send money
3. Parking

So instead of doing *100#, then calling, then replying 1, then calling again, to enter option number 1, I can dial directly using:

*100*1#

Which puts me directly inside "Check account" menu. If you have more options, you can go deeper directly by

*100*1*2*1*3#

Which is equivalent of entering the menu and then options 1, then suboption 2, then suboption 1 under it, then finally suboption 3. I use this all the time.

Comment: That's definitely helpful for situations where you don't have to input anything into the menu but in my situation, I'm prompted to enter a '1' to confirm a transaction.  I got around it by installing AutomateIt on an Android phone along with the Hacker's Keyboard and using AutomateIt to tab through the interface of the menu and enter what I needed.

Comment: @damir-kasipovic some USSD services need alphanumeric input in the sub menu. any idea how do I enter it directly?

Comment: @sandeepd I don't think that alphanumeric characters can be written into the phone dialer, and that is essentially what we are using here. I've had the same issue with paying for parking using USSD (our operator had that option) and I could automate it only up to registration part, then I had to type in the car's plate manually so I guess that's max you can do, automate up to the alphanum entry, and then type.

Comment: @damir-kasipovic Okay. In one app I saw alphanumeric data encoded and then sent, maybe that can be specific to that service(operator) only then.

Comment: @webo did this answer work for you? I tried one ussd service it only brings the top menu. Another ussd service rejected as unknown service. Perhaps it depends on the setting of the USSD application.

Comment: @kampangala: No, it didn't work for me because there was some input required for confirmations and such. As mentioned above, I used a couple apps to simulate manual input and perform the necessary tasks.